# Script tag in ng repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to set a an elements that are intially hidden but the script tag inside my ng-repeat is only executing once.

```
<h2 class="primary-header"> Get Settings </h2>
<div ng-repeat='feature in features'>
  <p></p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
    ng-click='genericGet(feature.func)'>

    {{feature.tag}}
  </button>
  <div ng-hide={{feature.hide}}>
    <pre>
      {{feature.status | json}}
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>


$scope.features =[];
$scope.features[0] = {};
$scope.features[0].tag = 'pop';
$scope.features[0].hide = true;
$scope.features[0].status = '';
$scope.features[0].func = 0;
$scope.features[0].url = 'pop';

$scope.genericGet = function(number){
          $scope.features[number].hide = false;
}
```

Comment: use ng-hide directive

Comment: This is just not how to work with angular. Use scope data models and core directives to manage things like this. To set display none as default use css

Comment: It's a bad idea for hide elements in angular, but you can define a function at top and pass 'feature.htmlID'

Comment: Ok so I tried ng-hide and it works when I declare the feature array in the controller where I have a boolean variable that determines whether the element is show/hide. However, when I call "genericGet(feature.func)" I can't seem to show/hide anything. Is it out of scope or something?

Comment: Show relevant controller code for `genericGet()`

Comment: Angular does not template inside `<script>` tags. This is incorrect: `document.getElementById('{{feature.htmlID}}').style.display = "none";`

Comment: -charlietfl Edited the post. It starts hidden but I can't unhide it.

Comment: Turns out {{feature.hide}} is supposed to be feature.hide